# Adjust linear regression penalty for under/over-estimations

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear

Basically I have a case where under-predictions are worse than over-predictions. Is there a way to penalize the linear regression model during training according to some predefined ratio?

E.g. I want to define that, for an actual value 10, predicting 9 and predicting 12 has equivalent penalty. (And not 9 and 11 as per default).

I guess my question is, is this something that is acceptable to do in the first place, and how would one best go about it?

PS. Maybe there is a reasonable approximation to solving this - without meddling with the least squares function. E.g. I've tried increasing the y (output) values by 1-2% and that moves me in the right direction, though requiring to incrementally test for the best % increase (not the worst thing..).

Comment: If you do training as in *training and validation*, you have to specify the loss function. Just specify one that suits you. Is that what you mean by *to penalize the linear regression model*?

Comment: Sorry my terminology is so dodgy. Yea so basically I would like to add a factor to the loss function during least squares data fitting. Unfortunately in scikit-learn doing this means having to meddle with the underlying scipy and then C code.. so I'm wondering if there's some alternative solution, but I guess not.

Comment: OK, that's not what I was thinking of. That means you would not choose an OLS-fitted model based on a validation set using a skewed loss function but would rather want a model that uses a skewed loss function for fitting itself. I do not have an idea how to implement that.

Comment: *Expectiles* might be a relevant keyword.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to do something like the quantile regression loss.

$$
l_{\tau}(y_i, \hat y_i) = \begin{cases} 
      \tau\vert y_i - \hat y_i\vert, & y_i - \hat y_i \ge 0 \\
      (1 - \tau)\vert y_i - \hat y_i\vert, & y_i - \hat y_i < 0 
   \end{cases}
$$

Then we add up each individual $l$ to get a loss $L$ for the whole model.
$$
L_{\tau}(y, \hat y) = \sum_{i=1}^n l_{\tau}(y_i, \hat y_i)
$$

You can figure out $\tau$ to balance the costs of high misses and low misses. I will demonstrate using your example where missing high by $2$ and missing low by $1$ should give equivalent penalties.

$$
(1-\tau)\vert 10 - 12\vert = \tau\vert 10 - 9\vert\\
(1-\tau)\vert -2\vert = \tau\vert1\vert\\
(1-\tau)\times 2 = \tau\times 1\\
1-2\tau = \tau\\
1 = 3\tau\\
\implies\\
\tau = 1/3
$$